# Sending data via WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

I was wondering how you can send data from the client to the host.  Currently I have 2 projects and one WCF library.  One of the projects is a pump which is the client and I want it to be able to send data to the host?  Although I may have a misunderstanding of how WCF works.  I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction.  The problem requires me to use WCF.  I want to be able to pass a list of strings to the host.

Comment: Searching on google for: How to use WCF gives you enough results to start with

Comment: Sorry, this question is not a good fit for SO.  Please research the topic on your own until you have specific questions on how to solve a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF can send data over many different transport protocols like MSMQ and http. It also enables message security, distributed transactions and other more complex features of a distributed system.

You need to create a WCF service, which is available as a template in Visual Studio. The server should be hosted as a stand alone program os as a web application in IIS.

Afterwards you need to create a client, that can communicate with the server.

WCF is however a large and complicated framework and you should not expect to be able to just scratch the surface and build a system. You need some googling and could possibly start [with MS own tutorials.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712.aspx)

If you need real useful answers you should be more specific about your program and the client and server operations as well as the deployment scenario.

Comment: Hi faester thank you for your input.  Currently I am trying get my pump to pass data to my POS terminal where the customer will go to pay.  I have stored my pump information e.g. how much the user will pay etc... in a list and want to pass it over to the POS terminal

Comment: Sounds like MSMQ to me :) But why are you so certain that WCF is the right choice for you?

Answer (score 1):

As [faester](https://stackoverflow.com/users/540968/faester) already said, WCF is a large framework and you can not make a good application by just copy-pasting the code into your project.
You should really read into the matter and then create your programming masterpiece.

[faester](https://stackoverflow.com/users/540968/faester) gave you a link, but it's for basic WCF client-server communication.

Here are some good links on sending and receiving data via WCF:

1. [Data transfer and architectural overwiev](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/aa347789(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. [Using the Message class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ms734675(vs.110).aspx)

For a simpler, task-oriented view of how to send and receive data, see:
[Specifying Data Transfer in Service Contracts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ms732038(v=vs.110).aspx)

I hope that this will help you and the people yet to come to this question.